# How to find intersect indexes and values in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I try to convert code from Matlab to python
I have code in Matlab:

```
[value, iA, iB] = intersect(netA{i},netB{j});
```

I am looking for code in python that find the values common to both A and B, as well as the index vectors ia and ib (for each common element, its first index in A and its first index in B).

I try to use different solution, but I received vectors with different length. tried to use numpy.in1d/intersect1d , that returns bad not the same value.
Thing I try to do :

```
def FindoverlapIndx(self,a, b):
    bool_a = np.in1d(a, b)
    ind_a = np.arange(len(a))
    ind_a = ind_a[bool_a]
    ind_b = np.array([np.argwhere(b == a[x]) for x in ind_a]).flatten()
    return ind_a, ind_b

 IS=np.arange(IDs[i].shape[0])[np.in1d(IDs[i], R_IDs[j])]
 IR = np.arange(R_IDs[j].shape[0])[np.in1d(R_IDs[j],IDs[i])]
```

I received indexes with different lengths. But both must be of the same length as in Matlab's `intersect`.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094083/find-the-overlap-between-2-python-lists

Comment: *"I try to use different solution..."*.  Post what you've tried and maybe someone can help.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MATLAB's `intersect(a, b)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) returns:

- common values of `a` and `b`, sorted
- the first position of each of them in `a`
- the first position of each of them in `b`

NumPy's `intersect1d` does only the first part. So I read its [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L332) and modified it to return indices as well.

```
import numpy as np
def intersect_mtlb(a, b):
    a1, ia = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
    b1, ib = np.unique(b, return_index=True)
    aux = np.concatenate((a1, b1))
    aux.sort()
    c = aux[:-1][aux[1:] == aux[:-1]]
    return c, ia[np.isin(a1, c)], ib[np.isin(b1, c)]

a = np.array([7, 1, 7, 7, 4]);
b = np.array([7, 0, 4, 4, 0]);
c, ia, ib = intersect_mtlb(a, b)
print(c, ia, ib)
```

This prints `[4 7] [4 0] [2 0]` which is consistent with the output on [MATLAB documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#btcnv0p-11), as I used the same example as they did. Of course, indices are 0-based in Python unlike MATLAB.

**Explanation**: the function takes unique elements from each array, puts them together, and concatenates: the result is `[0 1 4 4 7 7]`. Each number appears at most twice here; when it's repeated, that means it was in both arrays. This is what `aux[1:] == aux[:-1]` selects for.

The array `ia` contains the first index of each element of `a1` in the original array `a`. Filtering it by `isin(a1, c)` leaves only the indices that were in `c`. Same is done for `ib`.

**EDIT**:
Since version 1.15.0, [intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) does the second and third part if you pass `return_indices=True`:

```
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 6])
xy, x_ind, y_ind = np.intersect1d(x, y, return_indices=True)
```

Where you get `xy = array([1, 2, 4])`, `x_ind = array([0, 2, 4])` and `y_ind = array([1, 0, 2])`