# Finding longest overlapping ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I have ranges in a list like:

```
ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]
```

I would like to find the longest ranges that can be constructed from these *(when they overlap with each other)*.

Expected output:

```
[(1, 70), (75, 92)]
```

I have a solution, however it is way too complicated, and I am sure there must be an easier solution to this problem

My solution:

```
def overlap(x, y):
    return range(max(x[0], y[0]), min(x[-1], y[-1]) + 1)

ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]

beg, end = min([x[0] for x in ranges]), 0
for i in ranges:
    if i[0] == beg:
        end = i[1]
while beg:
    for _ in ranges:
        for i in ranges:
            if i[1] > end and overlap(i, [beg, end]):
                end = i[1]
    print(beg, end)
    try:
        beg = min([x[0] for x in ranges if x[0] > end])
        for i in ranges:
            if i[0] == beg:
                end = i[1]
    except ValueError:
        beg = None
```

Output:

```
1 70
75 92
```

Comment: isn't it a question related to genomic coordinates (spotted you are a bioinformatician)? If you don't need this function embedded in your own code, why not checking available tools such as bedtools?

Comment: Are your ranges open or closed at the ends?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong I need this piece code for a very simple use case. I want to represent the places of a protein sequence which have PDB structures. As there are lots of overlapping, I need such a code.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh They are closed.

Comment: @Georgy The accepted answer there is far better than any answer here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can sort your input by the start of the ranges, then iterate through them.  At each item, it is either added to the current range (if the start is less than the end of the current range) or we yield out current range and begin accumulating a new range:

```
def overlaps(ranges):
    ranges = sorted(ranges)  # If our inputs are garunteed sorted, we can skip this
    it = iter(ranges)
    try:
        curr_start, curr_stop = next(it)
        # overlaps = False  # If we want to exclude output ranges not produced by overlapping input ranges
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for start, stop in it:
        if curr_start <= start <= curr_stop:  # Assumes intervals are closed
            curr_stop = max(curr_stop, stop)
            # overlaps = True
        else:
            # if overlaps:
            yield curr_start, curr_stop
            curr_start, curr_stop = start, stop
            # overlaps = False
    # if overlaps:
    yield curr_start, curr_stop

print(list(overlaps([(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)])))
# [(1, 70), (75, 92)]

print(list(overlaps([(20, 30), (5, 10), (1, 7), (12, 21)])))
# [(1, 10), (12, 30)]
```

Comment: I like how readable this is. Although, don't you need to handle specially the _first_ and _last_ range? This solution would currently output them even if they don't overlap, right?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong I missed that requirement.  I think the easiest way to include it would be to add a boolean `overlaps = False` whenever we create a new current range.  We update it to `True` if the range overlaps, and check it before yielding the range (just silently discarding it if `overlaps` is false)

Comment: Agreed. I wrote a similar answer without seeing yours a few minutes ago, sorry for the miss.

Answer (score 9):

you can use zip to group all the start values and end values of each range pair. If the start value is lower than the previous end value then there is an overlap so remove that start and end value. we are using an int to track which index in each low and high list we are looking the low index is always one higher than the high index.

```py
#split the numbers in to the low and high part of each range
#and set the index position for each of them
ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]
low, high = [list(nums) for nums in zip(*ranges)] 
l, h = 1, 0

#Iterate over the ranges and remove when there is an overlap if no over lap move the pointers
while l < len(low) and h < len(high):
    if low[l] < high[h]:
        del low[l]
        del high[h]
    else:
        l +=1
        h +=1

#zip the low and high back into ranges
new_ranges = list(zip(low, high))
print(new_ranges)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 70), (75, 92)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Could be done using `functools.reduce`:

```py
from functools import reduce

ranges = [(1, 50), (45, 47), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]

reducer = (
    lambda acc, el: acc[:-1:] + [(min(*acc[-1], *el), max(*acc[-1], *el))]
    if acc[-1][1] > el[0]
    else acc + [el]
)
print(reduce(reducer, ranges[1::], [ranges[0]]))
```

Gives:

```
[(1, 70), (75, 92)]
```

Hard to put into words, but it uses `reduce` to go through the ranges. If the last tuple in the range and the next provided overlap (`if acc[-1][1] > el[0]`), it creates a new range from the `(min, max)` of both and then replaces this new combined range to what was behind it (`acc[:-1:] + [(min, max)]`), otherwise simply adding the new range to the end (`acc + [el]`).

Edit: After reviewing other answers, updated to take min/max of the two ranges compared instead of just first and last

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you iterate your ranges only once, but keep in memory the current range being expanded, like so:

```
def overlaps(r1, r2):
    assert r1[0] <= r2[0], "Assume ranges sorted by first coordinate"
    return (r2[0] <= r1[1] <= r2[1]) or (r1[0] <= r2[0] <= r1[1])

ranges = [(1, 50), (45, 47), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]


def fuse_ranges(ranges):
    output_ranges = []
    curr_r = list(ranges[0])
    curr_overlap = False  # Is the current range already overlapping?

    # Assuming it is sorted by starting coordinate.
    for r in ranges[1:]:
        if overlaps(curr_r, r):
            curr_overlap = True
            curr_r[1] = max(curr_r[1], r[1])  # Extend the end of the current range.
        else:
            if curr_overlap:
                output_ranges.append(curr_r)
                curr_overlap = False
            curr_r = list(r)
    if curr_overlap:
        output_ranges.append(curr_r)

    return output_ranges


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fuse_ranges(sorted(ranges, key=lambda r: r[0])))
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1, 70], [75, 92]]
```

Not sure my solution can be much less verbose than yours though...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Counter` container from the `collections` package and then perform set operations on the combinations of `Counter` objects you get using `itertools`.

Something along the lines of:

```
ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]
import collections, itertools
import numpy as np

out = []
for range in ranges:
    data = np.arange(range[0], range[1]+1)
    out.append(collections.Counter(data))

for x,y in list(itertools.combinations(out, 2)): # combinations of two
    if x & y: # if they overlap
        print(x | y) # get their union
```

will get you something close to what you want:

```
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 20: 1, 21: 1, 22: 1, 23: 1, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 1, 28: 1, 29: 1, 30: 1, 31: 1, 32: 1, 33: 1, 34: 1, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1, 41: 1, 42: 1, 43: 1, 44: 1, 45: 1, 46: 1, 47: 1, 48: 1, 49: 1, 50: 1, 51: 1, 52: 1, 53: 1, 54: 1, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 1, 58: 1, 59: 1, 60: 1, 61: 1, 62: 1, 63: 1, 64: 1, 65: 1, 66: 1, 67: 1, 68: 1, 69: 1, 70: 1})
Counter({75: 1, 76: 1, 77: 1, 78: 1, 79: 1, 80: 1, 81: 1, 82: 1, 83: 1, 84: 1, 85: 1, 86: 1, 87: 1, 88: 1})
Counter({84: 1, 85: 1, 86: 1, 87: 1, 88: 1, 89: 1, 90: 1, 91: 1, 92: 1})
```

If you keep doing this for multiple layers you'll get the supersets you want. You can find more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094083/find-the-overlap-between-2-python-lists) on how to use `Counter`.

Answer (score 3):

Question: Finding longest overlapping range in ranges

```
ranges1 = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]
ranges2 = [(1, 50), (40,45), (49, 70)]


def get_overlapping(ranges):
    result = []
    start = 0
    end = ranges[0][1]

    for i, node in enumerate(ranges[1:], 1):
        if end > node[0]:
            if end < node[1]:
                end = node[1]
            continue

        result.append((start, i - 1))
        end = node[1]
        start = i

    else:
        result.append((start, i))
    return result
```

Usage:

```
for _range in [ranges1, ranges2]:
    result = get_overlapping(_range)
    for o in result:
        start, end = _range[o[0]], _range[o[1]]
        print(start[0], end[1])
    print()
```

Output:

```
1 70
75 92

1 70
```

Comment: What if you have the following ranges: `[(1, 50), (40,45), (49, 70)]`? One would expect the "1 70" to be outputted, however because of your line `if ranges[i - 1][1] > node[0]`, it will not give the correct fused range.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong ***"One would expect the `"1 70"` to be outputted"***: Why, `, 45), (49, ` is not overlapping?

Comment: Well, maybe the OP could clarify, but I understood that he wants to take _series_ of overlapping ranges and merge them. In my proposed list, `(1,50)` overlaps with `(40, 45)` _and_ `(49, 70)`.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Got your point, therefore `(40, 45)` should be skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple iterative function:

```
def merge_range(rng):
    starts, ends = [], []   
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(rng):
        if i > 0:
            if x<= ends[-1]:
                ends[-1] = y
                continue
        starts.append(x)
        ends.append(y)
    return list(zip(starts, ends))
```

Outputs:

```
merge_range([(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)])
# [(1, 70), (75, 92)]

merge_range([(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92), (99, 102), (105, 111), (150, 155), (152, 160), (154, 180)])
# [(1, 70), (75, 92), (99, 102), (105, 111), (150, 180)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a set to eliminate duplicates, and a sorted list to iterate through, the following should work.

### Code:

```
ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]

all_nums = sorted(list(set(x for r in ranges for x in range(r[0], r[1]))))

i = all_nums[0]
print(i, end=' ')
while i < all_nums[-1]:
    if i not in all_nums:
        print(i)
        i = all_nums[all_nums.index(i-1) + 1]
        print(i, end = ' ')
    i += 1
print(i+1)
```

### Output:

```
ranges = [(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)]

1 70
75 92


ranges = [(1, 50), (55, 70), (75, 82), (84, 88), (87, 92)]

1 50
55 70
75 82
84 92
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the already posted answers use loops. Have you considered a [recursive solution](https://repl.it/repls/NearPalegreenMegabyte) instead:

```
def merge(ranges):
  """Given a sorted list of range tuples `(a, b)` merge overlapping ranges."""

  if not(ranges):
     return [];

  if len(ranges) == 1:
    return ranges;

  a, b = ranges[0];
  c, d = ranges[1];

  # eg.: [(1, 10), (20, 30), rest]
  if b < c:
    return [(a,b)] + merge(ranges[1:]);

  # examples: [(1, 5), (2, 3), rest],
  #           [(1, 5), (2, 10), rest]
  return merge([(a, max(b, d))] + ranges[2:]);
```

## Example

```
>>> merge([(1, 50), (49, 70), (75, 85), (84, 88), (87, 92)])
[(1, 70), (75, 92)]
>>> merge([(1,10), (2,3), (2,3), (8,12)])
[(1, 12)]
>>> merge (sorted([(2,5),(1,3)], key = lambda x: x[0]))
[(1, 5)]
```